# I am not able to use createrepo in rhel6

Tags: rhel6

When I Mount a .iso file in any folder, the folder becomes write protected. so, I cannot use  createrepo coomand thin rhel6.
I mounted .iso file in/var/rhel. Now that folder became write protected. I am using all commands as root.

Comment: Hi!
Your question might be a better fit for https://serverfault.com/ which has a stronger focus on server- and networkadministration than StackOverflow.

Comment: This is not suitable for Server Fault @Jakob: they have a pretty high bar on quality, and expect professional level sysadmin questions. Superuser or one of the Linux sites ([Unix/Linux, Ubuntu) sound like a better choice for this. The question is answered here, though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/390608/unable-to-mount-iso-in-write-mode (and more on Google `how to mount iso read write linux`)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Pekka!